# How to show recursive data in template?

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-models

I have a model with ForeignKey = 'self', and I want to reflect all data from database via lists and sub lists:

here is my model:

```py
class Place(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='Place name', )
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ROLE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: the Django template language is deliberately designed to be for simple presentation logic only, not complex business logic. I think you will need to do this in your view function rather than the template.

Comment: you're not showing us what you've tried. You should have a [mcve] to show us what's the problem or specific issue you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Django template is not designed to handle complex logics. For example,
>   you **can't** write nested logic by using include tag like this:
>
> ```
> # foo.html
> {% if nodes|iterable %}
> <ul>
> {% for x in nodes %}
>   {% include "foo.html" with nodes=x %}
> {% endfor %}
> </ul>
> {% else %}
> <li>{{ nodes }}</li>
> {% endif %}
> ```
>
> Because Django template nodes get parsed and compiled before they get
>   rendered, and the compiling of the above code could fall into loops
>   and fail by hitting maximum recursion depth.
>
> Normally, a template tag just like {% nested nodes %}, which works
>   like a view but belongs to the scope of Django template, is all you
>   need.
>
> Moreover, you could transform the data to a flat one through a filter,
>   then loop over it easily:
>
> ```
> {% for x in nodes|nested_to_flat %}
> {% if x.start_nodes %}<ul>{% endif %}
> {% if x.end_nodes %}</ul>{% endif %}
> {% if x.start_node %}<li>{% endif %}
> {% if x.end_node %}</li>{% endif %}
> {% if x.is_data %}{{ x.data }}{% endif %}
> {% endfor %}
>
> # nested_to_flat
> @register.filter
> def nested_to_flat(nodes):
>     if isinstance(nodes, list):
>         yield {'start_nodes': True}
>         for node in nodes:
>             yield {'start_node': True}
>             for i in nested_to_flat(node):
>                 yield i
>             yield {'end_node': True}
>         yield {'end_nodes': True}
>     else:
>         yield {'data': nodes, 'is_data': True}
> ```
>
> This is similar to the idea of rendering a mptt tree or threaded
>   comments.